# Get less date from tree lines date field - openerp

Tags: python, odoo

I have in my sale.order.line custom date field "start_service".

I need to modify payment term system that it works not from now datetime but for example due 14 days before service start, in my situation it should be the less date from related to order lines start_service field.

Can anybody give the way i need to read to trace start_service column to get new field with these less date

we use odoo 8.0.1

[image]

Comment: your question is unclear for me what you want. Can you provide code or something helpful information regarding question?

Comment: [link](http://limousine-service.berlin/images/1.jpg) these is print screen of situation

Comment: can you provide the code what you have tried so far ?

Comment: the main problem is that i dont know how to get value from line to parent(

Comment: these is my final code if any one need

Answer (score 1):

Achieved by below code:

```
class bcs_order_fields(osv.osv):
    _inherit = 'sale.order'
    def get_min_date_from(self, cursor, user, ids, name, arg, context=None):
        res = {}
        for sale in self.browse(cursor, user, ids, context=context):                
            date_list=[]
            for sale_line in sale.order_line:
                if sale_line.date_start:
                    date_list=date_list+([sale_line.date_start])
            if date_list:
                res[sale.id]= min(date_list)
            else:
                res[sale.id]=0.0
        return res
```